# How to grab form data with dynamically added rows with some checkboxes in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a form like this

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Shift Name</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>End Time</th>
            <th>Apply To</th>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="shift_name">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="time" name="start_time">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="time" name="end_time">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="departments"><option>All Departments</option></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_sun">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_mon">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_tue">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_wed">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_thu">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_fri">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_sat">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="shift_name">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="time" name="start_time">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="time" name="end_time">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="departments"><option>All Departments</option></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_sun">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_mon">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_tue">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_wed">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_thu">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_fri">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_sat">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="shift_name">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="time" name="start_time">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="time" name="end_time">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="departments"><option>All Departments</option></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_sun">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_mon">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_tue">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_wed">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_thu">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_fri">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day_sat">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>

    </table>
</form>
```

you can also check here https://jsfiddle.net/nasir9bd/1twhcc79/

As you can see every rows have checkboxes to select days of the week. And more row can be added with javascript. How efficiently can I grab these checkbox values with PHP as only checked ones returns value. I just need the idea.

Comment: (1) inputs with the same name, ie. `name="day_sun"`, in the same form will be overwritten by the next input, and only the last value will be sent/posted. (2) to fix issue #1, and also solve your issue, use array names, ie. `name="day_sun[]"`. Now you can get all posted values. (3) but without setting the `key` of the array name, ie. `name="day_sun[1]"`, you will get mismatched checkbox values, as unchecked checkboxes don't sent/post. So link them by using the same key, ie. `name="shift_name[1]"`/`name="day_sun[1]"`

Comment: thanks, existed row elements can be linked by a key, but how to do that if new rows added dynamically by javascript

Comment: You can add the key with javascript, depending on what your js code is. For example (using jQuery for simplicity) -> `/* get # of rows */ var key = $('input[name="shift_name"]').length; /* use the key/row count as new key+1 */ $(body).append('<input name="shift_name['+(key+1)+']" />');`.

Comment: Or on page load, you can set a global value based on how many default rows - `var key = 4;`, then in your javascript code when you dynamically add, use that value `...['+key+']...`, and then increase it - `key++`

Comment: yes, that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: in php it is easy to get all data, even if dynamically added with javascript using a simple loop, ie. `foreach($_POST['shift_name'] as $key => $value) { echo $_POST['shift_name'][$key]; echo isset($_POST['day_sun'][$key]) ? 1 : 0; //etc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form values will only ever submit the last ones.
A form like this:

```
<form>
    <input name="banana" type="checkbox" value="1">
    <input name="banana" type="checkbox" value="1">
    <input name="banana" type="checkbox" value="1">
</form>
```

Will only submit the last one.
To use the same name, try making them array values:

```
<form>
    <input name="banana[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
    <input name="banana[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
    <input name="banana[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
</form>
```

Then, in PHP, you can access these by using `$_POST['banana']`, which will be an array of the values. You should also post a row_id or some other identifier inside your array values (i.e. `banana[1]`, `banana[2]`, `banana[3]`, etc) so that your other fields match up (i.e. `shift_name[1]` corresponds to `day_sun[1]` when processing).

When you dynamically add more rows, you will also need to increment the array keys accordingly.

Please note that you're also not closing your input tags for `shift_name`, `start_time` and `end_time`.

Comment: +1 specifically for mentioning using the `key` of `arrayName[key]`, since unchecked checkboxes are not sent/posted, so it often leads to incorrect data.

Comment: thanks, I fixed the closing tag. from your code banana values can be get for single row. How to do that if I have several rows and more rows may be added dynamically. That will make a big banana array and then how to distinguish each row data?

Comment: Hi Nasir - that's why you would add the [1], [2], [3] to ALL of your inputs, so that they're all in arrays - then you know that shift_name[3] corresponds to day_sun[3], as per comment in my answer.

Comment: When you dynamically add more rows, you will need to increment the array keys accordingly.

Comment: yeah, got the idea also from Sean's comment. thank you.

Comment: Excellent! Best of luck - if you found this answer to answer your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.